# Divide/Segregate certain amount evenly according to other 4 given amount in datagridview - C#

Tags: c#

Just need a little help.
I want to Divide/Segregate certain value according to other 4 given amount in datagridview, but how do I do that?

Example:

Lets say I have 3500

Then in the data grid view values are

```
| ----- | -------------- |
| 0     |                |
| 3000  |                |
| 1000  |                |
| 1000  |                |
```

What I'm trying to get: If value on the other is 0 it skips it or the value is 0.

```
| ----- | -------------- |
| 0     |      0         |
| 3000  |      3000      |
| 1000  |      500       |
| 1000  |      0         |
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you wanting SQL or C# code?

Comment: In you post above, please provide some input variables, and the style of coding you require. For example, `int[] {0, 3000, 1000, 1000}`, and `for-loop`.

Comment: Can it be done in any order? i.e. are 3000/3000, 1000/500 and 1000/1000, 1000/1000, 3000/1500 both acceptable solutions?

Comment: Also, is this for a winforms datagridview? Or WPF?

Comment: By "divide" do you mean "subtract"? By "skip" `0` do you mean "subtract `0`"? By unnamed column of values do you mean "Start with a value `N`, e.g. `3500`, and a column of values `V`. For each row in `V`: if `V <= N` then subtract `V` from `N` and copy `V` to the new column, else put `N` (aka the "remainder") in the new column and set `N` to zero?

Comment: And by "evenly" do you mean nothing whatsoever?

Comment: @HABO I took it to mean "Distribute". But then beyond that more specifically, "Deaggregate in steps", or "Subtract in steps". The opposite would be aggregate. I can see where Dave is coming from. I am quite forgiving of his language. If he clarifies that might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

That we have a model defined as:

```
public class Model
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Applied { get; set; }
    public Model(decimal amount, decimal applied) 
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Applied = applied;
    }
}
```

Which we bind to our `DataGridView` via a `BindingList`, you should be able to use the following:

```
decimal total = 3500M;

foreach (Model model in models)
{
    if (model.Amount < total)
    {
        model.Applied = model.Amount;
        total -= model.Amount;
    }
    else
    {
        model.Applied = total;
        total = 0;
    }
}
```

**Full Example (using WinForms, something similar can be achieved in WPF)**

```
public class Model
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Applied { get; set; }
    public Model(decimal amount, decimal applied) 
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Applied = applied;
    }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<Model> models = new BindingList<Model>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        models.Add(new Model(0, 0));
        models.Add(new Model(3000, 0));
        models.Add(new Model(1000, 0));
        models.Add(new Model(1000, 0));
        Calculate();
        MyDataGridView.DataSource = models;
    }

    private void Calculate()
    {
        decimal total = 3500M;

        foreach (Model model in models)
        {
            if (model.Amount < total)
            {
                model.Applied = model.Amount;
                total -= model.Amount;
            }
            else
            {
                model.Applied = total;
                total = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```